If blood is prohibited, what about hemolymph?
Some creatures, such as locusts and oysters, have hemolymph that serves the same purpose as what we normally call blood. Do any historical sources (from early church history, for example) address whether hemolymph qualifies as lifeblood, which Genesis 9:6 and Acts 15:20, 28–29 forbids from consumption?

One argument I see in favor of eating cooked oysters, even if hemolymph counts as blood, is if the only amount remaining is negligible. Even with the blood in land animals, the biblical procedure still leaves a trace amount of blood, but the amount that remains is so small (likely <1% of the original amount), that it doesn’t count. Can the same be said for the amount of hemolymph that remains in cooked oysters, that the amount remaining is less than 1%?

I think #1 is on topic, but the last question is... dubious. I would consider removing the request to draw conclusions and focus on whether there exist sources speaking to this specific issue. (Also, #2 might be more appropriate for Cooking.SE.)

I’ve narrowed it down to just one question now.

As for the second question, I asked it here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/129666/do-cooked-oysters-contain-hemolymph

I'm wondering if closing this question is appropriate. While it could indeed be written better it seems like it ought to be answerable, but I can't think of how I could possibly answer it.

@Joshua It seems to be answerable, and I even am aware of a potential source to answer this. On the Jewish Stack Exchange, someone linked to the following source, which says “the blood of fish and locusts” is permissible: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.66.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi. Although it says it’s permissible—which, for Christians, would depend on how much weight we give this source—it does refer to locusts’ hemolymph as “blood,” apparently. This might be a source showing that our distinction between blood and hemolymph was not one people made in Bible times.

This should not be closed. It addresses a Christian question, albeit a historic one. Based on the comments, it appears that there used to be a 2nd question which was not permitted. I would point out that shellfish are forbidden (Leviticus 11:9-12) And Locust/grasshoper, etc were handled in (Leviticus 11:21-24). As for Christians... See Mark chapter 7 where Christ explains food doesn't make you unclean, but what comes out of your mouth does.

Note to potential answers.  "Historical" means, if nothing else, extra-biblical.

"locusts … have hemolymph that serves the same purpose as what we normally call blood" — Not really. Insects don't breathe air, and their "blood" doesn't transport oxygen. See: How Do Insects Breathe and Do They Have Lungs?.

Another relevant Jewish source is Mishnah Eduyot 7:2, which suggests that it is permissible to preserve locusts in brine. From what I understand, this method involves the entire locust, including the hemolymph. This further suggests that hemolymph wasn’t historically understood as falling under the prohibition against consuming blood.
